# How to reverse an animation on mouse out hover on a absolute position element

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm hiding an element which holds text with position absolute since some screen readers won't read it if the opacity is zero. I want to use a fade in animation like the first box, so I used a simple animation function, but I can't get the fade out animation to work. Do you guys know why?

Thanks in advance!

```css
p {
    color: red;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.card.using-opacity .text-container {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.card.using-opacity:hover .text-container {
    opacity: 1;
}

.card.using-position-absolute .text-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    animation: fadeOut 1s;
}

.card.using-position-absolute:hover .text-container {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
    <p>This is how it's supposed to work in terms of animation/transition but it's not accessible</p>
    <div class="card using-opacity">
        <div class="text-container">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>This is accessible, but I can't get the mouse out animated</p>
    <div class="card using-position-absolute">
        <div class="text-container">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Do you mean prevent screen readers to read elements with `opacity: 0`?

Comment: I want the second box to behave like the first box, when hovering in and out. As you can see, I can't make the hovering out the work the same way as the first box.

Comment: You can't do this without `transition`.

Comment: What about with jQuery?

Comment: `opacity: 0` will make your element unavailable for screen readers in some cases (In general it won't if you don't use the `visibility` property), so if you ever use it, the same problem persists whether you use `position: absolute` or not.

Comment: Even if the opacity: 0 is used on the animation (triggered when hovering)?

Comment: Yup, if you want to let the screen readers read it without any action or toggle you shouldn't make any `opacity` and `visibility` modifications.

Comment: WOW I never though that screen readers would look at the code trigger by hovering. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if this is possible with jQuery?